# requirejs not validating cache (IE)

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, requirejs, cache-control

after the first request requirejs never validate the scripts, no request is being made to the server, all request are 200 (from cache).

My server returns all the necessary headers for validation (Last-Modifeid, ETag),
but none of them are being used to validate the script (304 like request).

During investigation of the subject I found out that this problem doesn't occur with xmlhttprequest (second request is 304 - not modified, as expected with provided ETag) , so maybe the problem is with requirejs? or script tag loading in IE? or both?

first request (200 OK):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEwIj.png)

second request (200 OK from cache):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcRW7.png)